# Deriving the relativistic point particle action from QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

In principle, the action of a free relativistic particle of mass $m$ and trajectory $x^\mu(\tau)$

$$ S = -m \int d\tau \sqrt{\frac{dx_\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}} $$

should be obtainable as the particle limit of a QFT action describing a free system. For instance, starting from the Klein-Gordon action. Nevertheless, I have been unable to find any derivation. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: There are some relevant references in this question/answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522717/

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly: yes, of course one would have to first quantize the theory to obtain a particle description. But once that is done, the action of a single particle should still follow in some limit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's sought-for derivation of the [worldline formalism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/worldline+formalism) essentially boils down to the observation that the point-mechanical propagator/2-point function integrated over a [Schwinger proper-time parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization) reproduces the corresponding field-theoretic propagator/2-point function, even in the presence of various background fields, see e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. O. Corradini & C. Schubert, *Spinning Particles in QM & QFT,* [arXiv:1512.08694](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08694); Subsection 1.5.1 eqs. (1.154-158).

Comment: Are you referring to e.g. Eqs. (1.136) & (1.137) in particular?

Comment: Well, that's OP's starting point.