# Classical Mechanics Lagrangian from Underlying Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

Does the K - T classical mechanics Lagrangian emerge from some structure of the Lagrangian of the underlying QFT?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Deriving the relativistic point particle action from QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607729/2451)

Comment: Hi, the classical behaviour of a QFT is given by the tree level interactions of the fields. Moreover, you may also apply the Euler-Lagrange equations to the field theory and forget about the quantum corrections, which will give you the corresponding classical K-T of the theory (the equations of motion). You can find good notes on this by David Tong [link](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html)

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, I'll review that link!

Answer (score 0):

> Does the K - T classical mechanics Lagrangian emerge from some structure of the Lagrangian of the underlying QFT?

Historically it went the other way, but you can probably most easily understand how the classical theory can "emerge" out of the quantum theory in the path integral formalism of quantum mechanics (and quantum field theory).

In the path integral formalism, the amplitude to go from one point to another is the sum over all paths of:
$$
e^{iS/\hbar}\;,
$$
where $S$ is the standard/classical form of the action:
$$
S = \int dt L\;,
$$
where $L = T- U$, and where $T$ is the kinetic energy and $U$ is the potential energy.

This $S$ is minimized at the classical path (and gives the classical equations of motion) and so you can see how the classical path "emerges" by looking at the path where the quantum phase is *stationary*.

The hard part then is understanding how to do the sum over all paths and get the quantum results. But Feynman elucidated it pretty well. His book that he wrote with Hibbs is a great reference in this regard.

Comment: Many thanks for the insight! I'm more of a 'fields' person than a 'many particle paths' sum (and I think Feynman himself came over to this later in life) and so was wondering in particular about the QFT Lagrangian and how the classical T - U could emerge from this?

Comment: How are you proposing to work with a "QFT Lagrangian" but not a path integral formalism?